# Round up or down to the nearest 100

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I use node or js to round a number up or down to the nearest 100 depending on which is the closest?

For example how can I round 7490 to 7500 or 7440 to 7400 depending on whats the closest?

Comment: divide by 100 -> round -> multipy by 100

Comment: Math.round(number/100)*100